# How to include source file(.java file) parallel to .class file in the generated jar using maven

Tags: java, class, maven, jar

I wanted to create my jars with wars with that should include source file(.java file) parallel to .class file in the generated jar using maven. (I know there are some plugins available to generate a separate xyy-sources.jar file. But I dont want to create a seperate source jar. I need a single jar file with both .class and .java file exists parallel)

Comment: can you explain the part about "wars"?

Comment: Why to you want to include sources along with .class files ? **NEVER EVER DO THAT**, you would waste space in the true executable for no gain. If you want a single package containing sources and executable jar, the common way is to first generate the executable jar and then generate a source jar containing a `bin` or `lib` directory with the executable jar in it.

Comment: I got the solution. You only have to add resources under build tag. for example. <build> <resources> <resource> <directory>src/main/java</directory> </resource> </resources> </build>. Now every jar and war file you creat would contain .java files also. :) Anyways, thanks so much for your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to add resources under build tag. 
For example.

```xml
<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      </resource>     
    </resources>
</build>
```

Now every jar and war file you creat would contain .java files also. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if including .java adjacent to .class is a very good idea. Any specific reason you want to do that?

If you need to include sources, you can create a separate source jar (which is not you asked for, but is recommended way) like this by executing mvn package

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-sources</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Does this help? http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html

Comment: This will create a separate jar file with classifier `sources` and not what OP wanted.

Comment: @khmarbaise: Atul already said *is not you asked for* but can you imagine a single reason to include sources in an *executable* jar along with .class files ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I edited my answer and added "(which is not you asked for, but is recommended way)" after khmarbaise's comment. So thanks to him for that comment. Anyway, I also am not able to guess reasons for including sources in executable jar.

Comment: the reason why I have to include source along with .classs was, to feed the war file into a tool for code analysis. that tool require both to show the correct lines that causes if any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand why you would want to do this, but you could use the [maven-resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) and specifically its [`copy-resource`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) goal to copy your java files to any location within your build directory. So for example to copy them to the `classes` folder which then gets included in the jar that is built automatically you could do the following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/src-files-location</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```