# How to include source files in a war with archiveClasses parameter?

Tags: maven

I have a war project, and I included the classes in a jar in WEB-INF folder by using maven-war-plugin archiveClasses set to true, but this only includes .class files.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
      <version>5</version>
      <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
      <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
      <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

How can I include .java files in the jar too? I have not found any way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried [including the sources as a resource](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25810405/2646526)?

Comment: @heenenee It works with maven jar plugin, not maven war plugin

Comment: One option is to move your .java files to another module, bundle them as a jar w/sources there, and then depend on that other module in your war module.